# Outlook 2010: conversation view hides email attachments

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I access the attachment to an email if a newer email didn't contain it and Outlook decides to group them into a conversation?
[image: conversation view of emails with attachment]

My workaround solution is to use the Outlook Web App of our Exchange server instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click one more time on the expand triangle to open the entire conversation, select the message with attachment and open it as usual.

Comment: Hurray, Outlook quirk demystified! Indeed, the triangle has to turn black before the attachment can be seen again.